# cleaning up a XML parent node with all child nodes in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

Im writing a PowerShell script for a game that I'm playing to assist with the trading.

I created an XML where I store all the informations I need. The XML looks like:

```
<stuff>
  <resource>
    <type Name="Cotton" ID="0000">
      <isDGV>1</isDGV>
      <Storage>666</Storage>
      <AvgBuyingPrice>
      </AvgBuyingPrice>
      <lastBuyingPrice>42</lastBuyingPrice>
      <lowestBuyingPrice>
      </lowestBuyingPrice>
      <highestBuyingPrice>
      </highestBuyingPrice>
      <AvgSellingPrice>
      </AvgSellingPrice>
      <lastSellingPrice>
      </lastSellingPrice>
      <lowestSellingPrice>
      </lowestSellingPrice>
      <highestSellingPrice>
      </highestSellingPrice>
      <BuyingPricesHistory-Last42>
        <price>62</price>
        <price>42</price>
      </BuyingPricesHistory-Last42>
      <SellingPricesHistory-Last42>
        <price>
        </price>
      </SellingPricesHistory-Last42>
      <TownsProducedIn>
        <town>Sampletown</town>
      </TownsProducedIn>
      <TownsNeededIn>
      </TownsNeededIn>
    </type>
    <type Name="Spices" ID="0001">
      <isDGV>0</isDGV>
      .
      .
  </resource>
</stuff>
```

Now I want to have the possibility to "clean" all the child nodes of a specific resource. So that for example `<Storage>666</Storage>` becomes `<Storage></Storage>` again.

This is what I thought should work, but apparently, it's not that easy?
(Code is not complete, but `$XMLfile` is loaded just fine as it's also used for displaying the values of the resources. the `saveXML` function does also work)

```cs
$target = $XMLfile.stuff.resource.SelectNodes('type/child::*') | where { $_.Name -eq "$resName" -and $_.ID -eq $ID }

        foreach ($Child in $target)
        {
            $Child.InnerText = ""
        }
        saveXML $xmlFilePathAndName
```

Even worse: I don't get any error messages out of that code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that your `SelectNodes()` returns *child elements of `type`*, while the `Name` and `ID` attributes are at the `type` parent element level. So the subsuquent `where ...` filter didn't find any element that match the attribute value criteria.

You can use XPath to filter `type` element by its attributes, and then return the child elements, all in one expression, like so :

```
$target = $XMLfile.stuff.resource.SelectNodes("type[@Name='$resName' and @ID='$ID']/*")
```

Notice that `child::` is the default axis in XPath, so when you remove it, leaving only the path separator `/`, the engine will implies that you want the default axis to be used here.

Comment: Thanks. You solution works perfectly. All the different ways of working with XMLs are still very confusing for me. Almost like Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) solution, the special-purpose declarative programming language designed to transform XML documents. In fact, XSLT scripts are well-formed XML files! Like most general purpose languages (C#, Java, Perl, PHP, Python, VB), command line interpreters such as PowerShell and Bash can run XSLT. Of course they can also call external processors ([Saxon and Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info)) and aforementioned languages with arguments.

**XSLT** Script *(save as external .xsl file; portable to other languages/platforms)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>      
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Re-Write for Empty Storage Element -->
  <xsl:template match="Storage">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PowerShell** Script

```
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output) {
    Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
    exit;
}

trap [Exception]{
    Write-Host $_.Exception;
}

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load($xsl);
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

Write-Host "generated" $output;
```

**Command line**

```
PS > powershell -File PowerShellScript.ps1 Input.xml, XSLTScript.xsl, Output.xml
```